# Batch file that creates another batch file in desired location

Tags: batch-file

Here's my current file (It's supposed to create a folder, goe to that folder and then create a batch file in *that* folder):

```
@echo off 

echo md C:\"Program Files (x86)"\AcceleratorTool\

echo cd C:\"Program Files (x86)"\AcceleratorTool\

>AcceleratorTool.bat (
 echo taskkill /f /im chrome.exe
)
```

Despite me putting `cd C:\"Program Files (x86)"\AcceleratorTool\` in, it keeps creating the file in `C:\Windows\System32`.

It's probably due to the fact that I have to (and do) run the original batch file as administrator, I'm assuming that's related.

Comment: You're not putting `cd C:\"Program Files (x86)"\AcceleratorTool\ ` in though, you're only `echo`ing it. Also Why are you creating a directory in the program files directory? _you're not creating or writing a program file!_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have some mistakes in your script.  Here is fixed functional version:

```
@echo off 
REM create the target directory    
mkdir "C:\Program Files (x86)\AcceleratorTool" 2>nul

REM stores your current directory and changes the to the target directory
pushd "C:\Program Files (x86)\AcceleratorTool"

REM echos the command into the .bat file
echo taskkill /f /im chrome.exe > AcceleratorTool.bat

REM returns to the original directory
popd
```

The comments explain the functionality. Don't forget that you have to have correct rights to access `Program Files (x86)`!

Comment: Thanks, I am known for making lots of mistakes, I'm really new to this.

Comment: @WELZ you should bookmark [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/). It's an invaluable reference, even for not "really new" people.

Comment: `pushd` without arguments only returns current call stack and doesn't do anything else. Use `pushd "C:\Program Files (x86)\AcceleratorTool"`

Comment: When you issue a make directory command using an already existing directory, you'll get an error, that error would probably be better off directed to `Nul`.

Comment: thank you for comments & Compo for fixing it.  All are valid.

Answer (score 1):

To write a file there's no reason to change directory to the destination location:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "dirName=AcceleratorTool"
Set PROCESSOR_ARCHITE|Find "64">Nul && (
    Set "dirBase=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\%dirName%"
) ||Set "dirBase=%ProgramFiles%\%dirName%"
If Not Exist "%dirBase%\%dirName%\" MD "%dirBase%\%dirName%" 2>Nul ||Exit /B
Echo TaskKill /F /IM chrome.exe /T>"%dirBase%\%dirName%\%dirName%%~x0"
```

Comment: nice script!  I wanted my version to be as close to the original as possible.